# What is =& in PHP?

Tags: php, operators

Look at this example.  There is a line:

```
  $client =& new xmlrpc_client('/xml-rpc', 'api.quicktate.com', 80);
  $client->return_type = 'xmlrpcvals';
```

What is the `=&` and what does the `->` in `$client->return_type` mean?

Comment: And it is deprecated in PHP 5.3x so dont use it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `=` and the `&` should* have a space between them - they're two different operators. The `&` means [get a reference to this](http://www.phpreferencebook.com/samples/php-pass-by-reference/).

The `->` is for object member access - this means assign 'xmlrpcvals' to the `return_type` member of `$client`.

* see comments for clarification

Comment: The `=` and the `&` do not need to have a space between them.

Comment: @treeface - what I mean by 'should' is that it's misleading to not have a space. I don't care what the parser thinks, I'm just thinking about the poor person reading that code and trying to work out what `=&` means.

Comment: @treeface: yes, the space is insignificant; however, Skilldrick is saying that `=&` is not treated by the parser as a single operator itself, unlike `=>` which is a single operator.

Answer (score 8):

Is to pass a variable by reference

```
<?php  
   $a = 5; 
   $b =& $a; 
   $b = 6; 

   echo "a: "; 
   var_dump($a); 
   echo "b: "; 
   var_dump($b); 
?>
```

output:

```
a: int(6)
b: int(6)
```

Answer (score 2):

The =& assigns the variable a reference to the object rather than copying it.  It is two separate operators (assignment and getting a reference) but they are often written together.

The -> is a member access operator; in the example it means to get the return_type that belongs to the XML-RPC client.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with the last question first;

> what is the -> in $client->return_type mean?

-> is the operator you use to access properties and methods of an *object* in PHP. Most languages, such as Java or Javascript use the dot operator for the same thing. It (probably) derives from the C syntax for accessing members of a struct.

Then that first question...

> what is the =& ?

The short version is, *in your example*, it's a relic you no longer need; a hangover from PHP4 which you no longer need if you use PHP5. But note this is specific to your example.

For the long version, so you really understand what's going on read http://derickrethans.nl/talks/phparch-php-variables-article.pdf about References in PHP

Answer (score 1):

This is called [returning by reference](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/4/15/4).

Comment: ...and this is not longer necessary in PHP5 where objects are always passed by reference.